# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i) $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have three distributions $W,Y,Z$ and I sample $n$ values $X_i$ from just *one* of these distributions, by first flipping a 3-sided coin to decide from which: with a probability $\alpha$ for $W$, a probability $\beta$ for $Y$ and a probability $\gamma$ for $Z$. Once the distribution was selected, the sampling of $X_i$ is done $i.i.d$. I would like to get an expression for $S$ in terms of the expectations of $W,Y,Z$ and $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$, where,

$$S=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}\biggl(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\biggr) $$

Note that due to the randomized choice of the distribution from which to sample *all* the $X_i$ from,  the $X_i$ are identically distributed but *not* independent.

From empirical simulations, I am getting that this limit is $>0$ for any three different distributions, and is $0$ only if they are the same.

Comment: Just an idea.  Let $X$ be the random variable $\alpha W + \beta Y + \gamma Z$ (you say $W, Y, Z$ are distributions, but I will use the notation for random variables instead). We may take all $X_i$ to be i.i.d. independent from $X$. Now you can use the central limit theorem to conclude that the variance of $S$ is the variance of some normal distribution.

Comment: (I don't know much about probability and may be making an error which is why the above is a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: "but *not* independent": can you explain ??

Comment: You say "and I sample $n$ values $X_i$ **i.i.d.*, from ..." and then you say 
"$X_i$ are identically distributed but *not* independent". So you contradict yourself. To my understanding the first is correct, the $X_i$'s are independent, but I may be wrong (now that I think of this again).

Comment: @Jimmy: I could have phrased it better but the OP is ultimately correct. $X_i$ are only $i.i.d$ once the distribution from which to sample from is chosen. But in the expression for $S$, which is what I'm interested in, they are not independent, due due to the randomized choice of the distribution from which to sample all the $X_i$ from.

Comment: @Omri Yes, I also thought so. So, say given $X_1$ you can say more about the distribution of $X_2 \mid X_1$ than about $X_2$ in the first place! Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why they are dependent.

Comment: $var(S_n)=var(E(S_n|B))+E(var(S_n|B))=n^2var(\mu_{123})+nC$. Hence $S=var(\mu_{123})$ where $\mu_{123}$ is distribution taking values of means of $W,Y,Z$ with corresponding probabilities and will be zero iff all 3 means are the same. $B$ here is a variable that describes from which distribution you are sampling.

Comment: Making a random choice of the distribution cannot introduce any dependency between i.i.d samples, can it ?

Comment: @Yves The choice is made initially and then all i.i.d samples come from the same distribution. Of course the samples are dependent. If one of the possible distributions is large constant and another is small constant, then seeing the first sample tells you all the others.

Comment: @A.S, thanks for your comment, but it is not all clear how to find the parameters in your solution. Ultimately I need an expression for $S$ in terms of the means of $W,Y,Z$ and the prior probabilities. Can you write your answer as an "answer" not comment...?

Comment: $\mu_{123}$ takes values $\mu_W,\mu_Y,\mu_Z$ with probabilities $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Hence you can compute $E\mu_{123}$ and $E\mu_{123}^2$ to find the variance.

Comment: @A.S: Thanks! Looks OK to me.

Comment: @A.S, could you address a new case I have in this setting: say $W,X,Z$ are each a sequence of RVs, $W_i, X_i, Z_i, i:1...n$ instead of single RVs, and I sample $n$ values from one of these sequences (again according to the prior probabilities), independently but thus not identically distributed. I would like again to find $S$, and the condition for which it would be zero, this time in terms of $E(W_i), E(X_i), E(Z_i), i:1...n$ (and the prior probabilities).

Comment: Sampling from a sequence with fixed probabilities just defines a new mixture distribution - so the problem gets reduced to the one already solved. Unless I misunderstood you. Be more descriptive if the case.

Comment: OK, so instead of $E(W)$ we will have $Sum(E[W_i])/n$, right? And the condition for $S=0$ would be $Sum(E[W_i])/n=Sum(E[X_i])/n=Sum(E[Z_i])/n$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mu=\alpha\mu_W+\beta\mu_Y+\gamma\mu_Z$$

$$S=\alpha(\mu_W-\mu)^2+\beta(\mu_Y-\mu)^2+\gamma(\mu_Z-\mu)^2.$$

Comment: yes thanks that looks correct.